# images not cached with self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate, cache, chrome

I'm experiencing a problem where certain content (images) are not being cached when loaded from an https connection. The issue is occurring on both local and remote hosts, both are using self-signed certificates.

Sample response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 17:22:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11-3+deb.sury.org~saucy+1
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, private
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Browser/OS: Chrome/Ubuntu

Are there any known issues with caching and self-signed certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Installing a commercial certificate resolved the above issue.